# JavaScript Object not working correctly

Tags: javascript

i am working on a cs:go jackpot site, but one part of the code wont seem to work...

```
   if (playersUnique[item.steamid] === undefined) {
    playersCounter++;
    helper.msg('added player');
    helper.msg(item.user);
    helper.msg(item.ava);
    helper.msg(item.steamid);
    playersUnique[item.steamid] = {
        'user': item.user,
        'ava': item.ava,
        'money': item.money,
        'steamid': item.steamid
    };
    helper.msg(playersUnique[item.steamid]);
```

All the values work correctly, but when i try to print out the playersunique with that persons steam id it writes "object object" And it keeps adding the person as a new person everytime it scans in a skin.

So the playerscounter will be equal to the amount of skins deposited.

Comment: "when i try to print out the playersunique with that persons steam id it writes "object object" — Well, yes. That's what happens when you convert an object to a string. What did you expect (the code which does that but which you haven't shared with us to do)?

Comment: "And it keeps adding the person as a new person everytime" — It shouldn't do unless you are changing the `steamid` each time, or you are testing for "adding as a new person" in some way other than how I would do it.

Comment: Your question title is "JS Array not working" but you don't seem to have an array anywhere here.

Comment: @Quentin `playersUnique` appears to be an array.

Comment: How are you printing out the player? `Object object` is what you get if you try to use an object as a string.

Comment: @Barmar — Since its being accessed by a steam ID, it looks more like an object.

Comment: @Quentin I didn't know the steam ID is a string, I assumed it was a number.

Comment: @Barmar — Even if it is a number, it isn't going to be a nicely sequential thing. The odds of wanting a sparse array are pretty low (especially with the size that numerical IDs on popular services tend to be).

Comment: Well to be honnest, i did not write the code myself.

But it does not  seem to work , do you not see any error in the code? :/

And the only playercounter++; there is is right there.

Comment: Thanks for quick response tho!

Comment: The steam id is a numerical string, that i can easely output on the command log

Comment: Sorry i assumed that variable was a array, im not verry hype on JavaScript and will eventualyl hire someone to deal with that part of the site

Comment: @DenduvetHan Correct. Why not change the title? (I put "correctly" in my edit because otherwise there was anothr question with the same title)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong, there was a bit of code that reset playersunique each time a new player was scanned for... Been finding way to muuch of these idiot buggs here!